# explodeModifier not working for imported model in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to do a face explode effect as seen in this example:   http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_tessellation

However the example uses THREE.TextGeometry and I am using an imported model using

THREE.JSONLoader();

```
            loader.load( "models/animated/Brain-New_2154_ft.js", function ( geometry ) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
                    color: 0x6249a3,
                    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
                    morphTargets: true,
                    overdraw: 0.5
                } );
```

How can I use an imported model for this effect? Do I have to convert the model to something before it's faces, vertices can be affected with the explodeModifier and TessellateModifier libraries?  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the THREE.ExplodeModifier() which is not included in the core, you have to explicitly import it in (see line 140 in your example).

The ExplodeModifier just loops through the vertices array in your geometry so it should work with any model type that can be successfully imported.

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10,10,10);

var explodeModifier = new THREE.ExplodeModifier();
explodeModifier.modify( geometry );

This gives you an array of faces you can manipulate the same way you do the vertices